# What connectivity will be best suited in terms of security and performance to connect on-premise to Azure PaaS Service?

Tags: azure, paas

How to connect on premise from Azure PaaS Service?

What connectivity will be best suited in terms of security and performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use private link to do this.
In terms of performance it depends on your IaaS Architecture and in what KPI you define.
Here is a link to a good Microsoft document:
[zero-trust-part-1-networking](https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2020/06/15/zero-trust-part-1-networking/)